# Locking/Unlocking functions with CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c++, multithreading, critical-section

So, when I use "EnterCriticalSection" & "LeaveCriticalSection" I throws an exception at me, this is my current setup:

```
void printer::Unlock()
{
    LeaveCriticalSection(&_cs);
}

void printer::Lock()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&_cs);
}
```

_cs is a CRITICAL_SECTION object created inside my class "printer" like this:

```
class printer {
private:
    static CRITICAL_SECTION _cs;
```

When I call "Lock" it throws the exception, I'm not really sure why, I've tried reading the MSDN but I dont quite 100% understand it.

(I dont want to use mutexes...)

Comment: Like it says in the documentation, "[Before using a critical section, some thread of the process must call InitializeCriticalSection or InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount to initialize the object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx)."

Comment: Hm.. why is that not done in the CRITICAL_SECTION ctor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add

```
InitializeCriticalSection(&_cs);
```

If that fails, you might try changing the CRITICAL_SECTION _cs to mutable rather than static, but that's kind of a shot in the dark.

Comment: That looks like it migth be the fix yea